# Is there a way to return multiple firebase methods in react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a react-redux application with firebase as the backend. When a user signs up, I store some user data under a collection "users" and other data under a collection called "roles".

```
 firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            newUser.email,
            newUser.password
        ).then((response) => {
            return firestore.collection('users').doc(response.user.uid).set({
                first_name: newUser.first_name,
                last_name: newUser.last_name
            })
        })
```

As at now, I am only able to add to "users". How can I add another method to add to "roles"?

Answer (score 1):

you can do so using Promises chaining

```
 firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                newUser.email,
                newUser.password
            ).then((response) => {
                return firestore.collection('users').doc(response.user.uid).set({
                    first_name: newUser.first_name,
                    last_name: newUser.last_name
                })
            }).then((response) => {
                return firestore.collection('roles').doc(response.user.uid).set({your_data})
            })
```